# Laravel - check is user logged in with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

Maybe is stupid question but is possible to check is user logged in with javascript...

How to check is user logged in with JavaScript?

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#facebook').click(function(){
        window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
        return false;
        setInterval(function() {
            @if {{Auth::check()}};
                alert('loged')
            @else
                alert('not loged')
            @endif
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

of course this doesn't work.

So I need when I click on `#facebook` to check every 5 seconds if user is logged in.

Comment: AJAX request to some custom method that will check if the user is logged in and return true/false that you can handle in your javascript.

Comment: yes, that is solution

Answer (score 4):

Send ajax request to a route some like `http://example.com/auth/check`

and return true/false from this route.

`Route::get('/auth/check',function(){
    return (\Auth::check()) ? True : False
});`

Or you can return some formatted JSON.

Comment: Or just return \Auth::check().